# xlwings set_mock_caller() return None

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

Windows 10, Python 3.6, xlwings 0.27.8

When trying to debug my code outside of `RunPython`, I keep stumbling on the following issue, for example:

```
import xlwings as xw
xlsx_file = 'anExcelFile.xlsm'
xlwx = xw.book(xlsx_file).set_mock_caller()
```

From there, I am hoping to be able to use `xlsw` as normally as such if I had used the routine from `RunPython`, but now, typing `xlsw` returns `None`

However, if i do:
`xlsx = xw.book(xlsx_file).set_mock_caller`

then `xlsx` contains:   `<Book ['anExcelFile.xlsm]>`
but still, `xlsx()` returns `None`.

Any lead on what I am getting wrong would help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally understood my issue.
As explained in [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=set_mock_caller#xlwings.Book.set_mock_caller), the code sequence should read as follows:

```
import xlwings as xw
xlsx_file = 'anExcelFile.xlsm'
xw.book(xlsx_file).set_mock_caller()  
# Sets the Excel file which is used to mock xw.Book.caller() 
# when the code is called from Python and not from Excel via RunPython.
# and then: 
xlsx = xw.Book.caller()
```

Now, `xlsx` returns:  `<Book [anExcelFile.xlsm]>`